# Magento 2 Get a list of Attribute Set Names and IDs

Tags: magento2, attribute-set

How would I get a **list of Attribute Set names and IDs** in Magento 2?

Edit: Adding code.

Edit 2: Added code that worked for me

```
<?php

namespace Company\CustomAttributes\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;


class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var OptionFactory
     */
    protected $optionFactory;

    /**
     * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OptionFactory $optionFactory)
    {
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
        //you can use this if you want to prepare options dynamically
        //$coll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* your Attribute options list*/

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $coll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::class);

        $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Attribute Set', 'value'=>'']];

        foreach($coll->toOptionArray() as $d){
            if($d['label'] !== 'Default') {
                $this->_options[] = ['label' => $d['label'], 'value' => $d['value']];
            }
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve flat column definition
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColumns()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        return [
            $attributeCode => [
                'unsigned' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'extra' => null,
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Custom Attribute Options  ' . $attributeCode . ' column',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to get it is to use the following source model : `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options`

You can inject it in your constructor then call the `toOptionArray()` method to retrieve all attribute sets name and ids.

Comment: I added code to the question based on what I think you said, however it's not working. So I'm not sure what I did wrong. Any chance you could take a look and point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @Jim for which purpose do you need this list exactly?

Comment: The list will be used to populate a drop down for a category attribute.

Comment: @Jim well in that case instead of using your custom class just use the class I posted directly it should do it ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the code above incase anyone else ever needs to do this.

Comment: I am getting error - when I applied the same as source in 'InstallData.php'. Error is -  "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options::setAttribute() in /home/shishamo/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php on line 547" .....My Magento version is -  2.1.6

Comment: perfect :)

Now how can get All attributes by attribute set name ?

Comment: This is a perfect solution when you want to populate a field with attribute sets in system.xml - eleminates the need for additional coding.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class AttributeList extends AbstractSource
{
    protected $_userFactory;
    protected $pageFactory;
    private $attributeSetRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepositoryInterface,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->pageRepositoryInterface = $pageRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function listAttributeSet()
    {
        $attributeSetList = null;
        try {
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new Exception($exception->getMessage());
        }

        if ($attributeSet->getTotalCount()) {
            $attributeSetList = $attributeSet;
        }

        return $attributeSetList;
    }

    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $attributeSetList = $this->listAttributeSet();
        if ($attributeSetList) {
            foreach ($attributeSetList->getItems() as $list) {
                $options[$list->getAttributeSetId()] = $list->getAttributeSetName();
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Working Solution

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;

class AttributeSetList extends AbstractSource
{
    private CollectionFactory $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getAllOptions(): array
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $attributeSetCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
            $attributeSetCollection->join(
                ['eavEntityType' => $attributeSetCollection->getTable('eav_entity_type')],
                'eavEntityType.entity_type_id=main_table.entity_type_id'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'eavEntityType.entity_type_code',
                ['eq' => ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE]
            );
            $this->_options = $attributeSetCollection->load()->toOptionArray();
            array_unshift($this->_options, ['value' => '', 'label' => __('Please select attribute set.')]);
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```